# Can I rely on the include guards in standard headers

Tags: c, include-guards

I want to know if I can rely on the particular definitions of the include guards in standard headers. If I look on my system with Visual Studio I can see, for example, that stdint.h has the `_STDINT` defined. My question is if I can rely on this `#define` for other compilers too. Basically, is it safe for me to do something like this:

```
#ifndef _STDINT
typedef char int8_t;
#endif
```

I know this might look stupid. Why not just include stdint.h you say? Well I'm writing code which may be deployed embedded targets, which might not be happy about including certain standard c headers. However, I want to be able to use them when they are available. Therefore, I want to be able to choose in the file that has `int main()` whether I want to include stdint.h or not.

Comment: short answer is no, and long answer is dear-god-don't-do-this. underscore #defines are reserved for the file scope only, so using them outside that file is risky at best.

The correct way to handle this (imho) would be to provide your own "stdint.h" iff it is not found on the target machine. I'd do an optional include directory, which is included if the compiler is not c99/posix compatible. then include stdint with `#include "stdint.h"`.

Comment: "an optional include directory, which is included if the compiler is not c99/posix compatible". Forgive my ignorance. How do I do that? Via compiler flag? Or another header which configures my system according to c99 defines?

Comment: @xaviersjs It's compiler dependent, but yes, it usually boils down to giving one extra path to compiler.

Comment: @xaviersjs This shouldn't be handled in the header file but rather as part of whatever build system you are using, I would think. I personally use CMake so `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CONCAT ("stdint.h"        H4H5_HAVE_STDINT_H)` takes care of that, but you'd have to set it up how you want it.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Your answer would _break_ in several scenarios without some kind of `configure` process to go beforehand. On GCC at least (and perhaps some other compilers), user-defined include paths (i.e. those passed as `-I`) are included _before_ system include directories; therefore this "optional" include will always become included, even if the system _does_ have its own `stdint.h`. Sometimes this may be sufficient (for example, if it's known that the entire application and all its compile-time deps only use a small well defined subset).

Comment: @mnunberg that is why I encouraged him to make it as part of the build system, NOT as include files. Also why its in comments and not in an answer...making downgradable C/C++ code is always like playing with fire.

Comment: Having all the #defines contained in some system header file is not a risk AND does not bloat the code.  So is not a problem in embedded systems.  The linker will only link code that is actually referenced in the body of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on a standard library header to declare exactly (and no more than) what it is specified to declare. This means that:

- If a feature is optional, the standard will specify a feature-test macro that you can check for with `#if` or `#ifdef`, to tell you if it is available on your platform. e.g. `threads.h` is optional in C11, so the standard specifies that `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is defined to 1 if the header is not available.
- If a feature is not optional, you should be able to assume it is present! If it isn't present, the compiler isn't conforming to the language version, and you'd better hope that this stuff is explicitly spelled out in the documentation, because you're into implementation-defined territory.
- Many features are provided as macros, or with associated macro definitions; you can therefore test for the existence of such features independent of the whole header.

So for the case of `stdint.h`, there is no feature test macro provided because the header is not optional. If it isn't present, the compiler really ought to be documenting that, and not claiming standard compliance. However, certain features within `stdint.h` are optional, and are therefore testable individually with their associated macros.

For instance, the exact-width integer types described in 7.20 (`int8_t` and so on) require associated macro definitions describing their maximum and minimum values (and that these macros specifically *not* be defined if the types are not available), so you can test for the specific availability of `int8_t` by testing whether `INT8_MAX` is defined after including the header.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no :). This is why things like `autoconf` and friends exist, to be able to actually compile small programs and test in advance to determine if the system contains specific symbols and headers; something which cannot be done in a single pass compilation of your program.

Case in point here, the "Visual Studio `stdint.h`" doesn't actually exist on older visual studio versions.

The correct solution, as pointed out above, is to use some kind of out-of-source configure system to determine what to do.

Sometimes, you might be able to get away with something simpler, depending on how large a subset you use from `stdint.h`:

- Use project-prefixed fixed with types (`my_I32` for example), and define them as being `int`; if it's known beforehand that all target platforms will have `int` as being a 32-bit integer.
- Use a project-supplied `stdint.h` and place the path of this file in your preprocessor search path. Note that this requires that your project *and any dependencies of this project, including system headers* will only use the subset of declarations defined in this file.